# 2020 Azure DevOps (onprem) is SOOOOO slow

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-server-2020

**Issue:** When going to our 2020 Azure DevOps (onprem) internal site - the page takes 2-4 minutes to load - any link thereafter takes 2-4 minutes to load. Everything eventually loads without error but this lag...UGH!

**Background**: Installed 2020 Azure DevOps on virtual server (Windows 2019) with 8 cores, 32GB RAM, HDD (C & D) 100GB each

I don't know if it's the installation or IIS or the server or something else that is ridiculously apparent to people who are way smarter than me - this is agonizing!

Comment: There is no obvious reason. It looks like your server is well specced for the job. With these specs Azure DevOps Server should be nice and speedy.

Comment: I have the issue randomly at times.  It's one of those things to figure it out will take diagnosing on the server through performance monitor, wireshark, sql tools, etc.  After some the 2-4 minute delays, it is like it all "wakes up" and starts working properly.  I'll continue to follow this thread!!

Comment: Does your IIS logs not say anything meaningful?

Comment: Do you have ElasticSearch service enabled? This causes severe issues for us, so we've disabled it.

Comment: We had a slow server sometimes, too. We later discovered that our IT dep that setup the server installed the express version of SQL server which is limited in the amount of cpu cores it's able to use (if i remember this correctly). Installing a proper version of SQL server solved the problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue. When opening the URL it took a long time to open the website (approx. 2 minutes) but no error was shown. The server event log showed different errors (e.g. TF30065). Restarting the Azure DevOps Server, clearing Cache etc. did not improve the situation. 
 
The culprit has then been identified as Kaspersky Antivirus. The solution was then to add the antivirus scanning exclusions from Microsoft. 
 [Antivirus exclusions for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/devops/antivirus-scanning-exclusions)

 
Hope that was helpful.